# Run code in specific part of URL in Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have an application which makes heavy use of features, separated by specific users, which have different roles.

The problem is that I want to restrict access to some templates, if, for instance, the user is not an Admin.

Currently, I have this:

```
Router.route('createUser', {
  path: '/admin/users/',
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    if(!isAdmin()) {
        Router.go('/');
    }
    this.next();
  }
});
```

But, specifying that `if(isAdmin())` call to every other route is a pain. I want to know if there is any other easy and less error prone way to do it.

Maybe some regex magic would do, but I don't seem to find any examples of use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First i will recommend you to read this [meteor:common-mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) on the **profile editing** part

So i will recommend you to better use the [alanningroles-meteor package](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles).

Is super easy to use, here is a [Online DEMO](http://leaderboard-roles.meteor.com) and the [Source Code](https://github.com/Ethaan/leadboard-roles) if you have doubts.

On the router level you can create an `onBefore` hooks like this.

```
isAdmin = function(){
  var currentUser = Meteor.user()
         isUserSuperAdmin = Roles.userIsInRole(currentUser,'Super-Admin'); //using alaning roles.

           if(isUserSuperAdmin){ //or use isAdmin(); 
             this.next();
           }else{
             this.render('accessDenied')
           }
}

Router.onBeforeAction('accessDenied', {only: ['admin','otherAdminRoute',etc]});
```

Comment: Awesome links! I will sure look into them. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can have an `onBeforeAction` hook combined with `only` for all routes like so:

```
var isAdmin = function() {
    // Whatever logic you have for checking admin
    if (!admin) {
        Router.go("/");
    }
    this.next();
}

Router.onBeforeAction(isAdmin, {
  only: ["admin/users"] // Specify other admin templates here
});
```